# How to not install google cloud sdk by default while creating a Compute Engine instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, boto

Whenever I create a Compute Engine instance, it installs the google-cloud-sdk by default on the server. And that installs and configures BOTO on the server and set environment variables for that.

What I want is to not have anything remotely related to BOTO on the server.
I have tried the documentation in various places but no luck anywhere.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Stack Overflow has much more experience with this than most folks here.

Comment: @quadruplebucky thanks. I will try asking it there

Comment: @peterh Thanks for pointing that out. Auto Correct always takes its toll. :)

Comment: Had it been too hard to fix it? Btw, what the heck is a "boto"? My autocorrect algorithm says you tried to write "both", but I am not sure. There is an "edit" link below your question, you can always edit your own posts. You don't need a native-level English to communicate here, but if you can avoid [this top 6 most annoying mistakes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers), you posts will be probably okay. If your question is unclear, incomprehensible, it will be closed.

Comment: @peterh thanks for pointing out the resources. I will surely look into that and try to not make these mistakes again. Also, BOTO is a python package that provides interface to Amazon Web Services. you can find info about boto here - [link](https://github.com/boto/boto) . It's quite popular actually :)

Comment: @peterh As far as the clarity of question goes. I think it's quite clear actually, It states that google compute engine automatically install and configure boto with google-cloud-sdk and I want to remove them. That's it. If there's anything else that should be added, please let me know :)

Comment: Okay, I improved the edit. A most important case from the border of bad spelling -> unclarity line, if you simply don't use sentences. I broke you text up to sentences. All of them should end with a ".", "?" or "!" ("." is most likely here).

Comment: @peterh Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it. I will surely look into the link you gave me in prior comments and make sure that I don't make these mistakes again.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud SDK is pre-installed on the [public images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#os-compute-support) provided by Google. It is a useful tool when your VM needs to interact with other resources in your project.

I am not sure what is the reason you want to uninstall it. When you create a VM, you are given the possibility to define the service account and the scopes that will work with that VM. That service account will be the one authenticated on the gcloud tool running in the VM. That account and the scopes of the VM will be the ones [limiting access to other resources](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gce-discussion/service$20account$20scopes|sort:relevance/gce-discussion/3QIjjawlqkY/-2RjElOkBgAJ). For additional information check [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes)

You can always choose not to link a service account at the creation time of the VM.  If you do that, Cloud SDK will not have any credentials to access any other resources in your project.
i.e.

```
gcloud auth list
No credentialed accounts.
To login, run:  $ gcloud auth login `ACCOUNT`
```

Check [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gce-discussion/D2tXsv3sPWU/QKGHYN-eCAAJ) which also addresses the same topic.
If you really want to remove Cloud SDK, you can follow the steps provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344371/completely-uninstall-google-cloud-sdk-mac)

Comment: Hi Carlos. Thanks for the effort. However, I am not particularly trying to un-install google-cloud-sdk but BOTO instead. Do you happen to have any insights on that?

Comment: That seems to be somehow different. I uninstalled the package on a Debian image following the commands [provided here](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/trusty/python-boto?action=remove). If you need to spin new VMs without it, you can create a [custom image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#custom_images) (after removing the package). Then use that image instead of the public one to spin the other VMs.